# mod_wsgi : Target WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python-2.7, centos7, openstack

**Environment: +Centos 7.9 +python2.7 +openstack 4.0.2 (Train)
+ldd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so**

```
    ___________________
    inux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc57db8000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fb54ccfb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb54cadf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb54c8db000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fb54c6d8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb54c3d6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb54c008000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb54d2f1000)
    ____________________

    2022-09-27 18:43:08.205406 ArgsAlreadyParsedError: arguments already parsed: cannot register CLI option
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925261 mod_wsgi (pid=15104): Target WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925308 mod_wsgi (pid=15104): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public'.
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925332 Traceback (most recent call last):
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925410   File "/usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public", line 52, in 
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925575     application = initialize_public_application()
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925591   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/wsgi.py", line 24, in initialize_public_application
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925612     name='public', config_files=flask_core._get_config_files())
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925634   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/flask/core.py", line 157, in initialize_application
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925672     keystone.server.configure(config_files=config_files)
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925681   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/server/__init__.py", line 28, in configure
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925696     keystone.conf.configure()
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925703   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystone/conf/__init__.py", line 137, in configure
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925718     deprecated_since=versionutils.deprecated.STEIN))
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925726   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2055, in __inner
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925742     result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925751   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2333, in register_cli_opt
    2022-09-27 18:43:09.925764     raise ArgsAlreadyParsedError("cannot register CLI option")
```

Comment: What command are you trying to issue? It says it can't `register CLI option`, it's likely the cause, not the python module error.

Comment: do you find the answer?